# In Angular 2 reactive form doesn't update values using ngModel and formArrayName

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, primeng

I have a simple Reactive Form in Angular 2 and my form doesn't detect change of cells of a primeng data table. The html is:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<p-dataTable [value]="dataMenu" [editable]="true" formArrayName="menu">
    <p-column field="menu" header="Menu"></p-column>
    <p-column field="price" header="Price" [editable]="true">
        <template let-row="rowData" let-i="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
            {{row.price}}
        </template>
        <template let-row="rowData" let-i="rowIndex" pTemplate="editor">
            <input type="number" pInputText [(ngModel)]="row.price" name="test" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
        </template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

and the .ts file is:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group( { //fb is FormBuilder
    menu: this.fb.array([]),
});

this.setDataMenu(this.dataMenu);
...
setDataMenu( menu: Array<any> ) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['menu'];
    for ( let m of menu ) {
        control.push( this.fb.control(m, validatePrices) );
    }
}

function validatePrices( c: FormControl ) {

    return ( c.value != null && c.value.price) ? null : {
        validatePrices: {
            valid: false
        }
    };
}
```

The problem is that the validation fires only at the beginning and when the value of "dataMenu" changes, the form does not detect this change.

Comment: Could you add the (JSON) data that you are showing in your template?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to use two-way binding, `[(ngModel)]` with Reactive Forms?

You should use the `formControlName` attribute with your `input` tag.

Example :

Create your form

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group( { //fb is FormBuilder
    menu: this.fb.array([]),
});
```

Subscribe to the formGroup or individual controls to listen for values.

```
this.myForm.get('menu').valueChanges(val => this.menuValue = val);
```

In your template make this simple change.

```
<input type="number" pInputText formControlName="menu" name="test" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
```

As you can see I have removed `[(ngModel)]` and added `formControlName` instead.

### Validation

You can then easily validate changes made to the controls. One simple method would be to just pass the `val` returned from the subscription callback into a validation method.

The preferred approach would be to use [ValidatorFn](https://toddmotto.com/reactive-formgroup-validation-angular-2#custom-validation-properties) though

Comment: I tried to remove `[ngModelOptions]` and add `[formControlName]="i"` but I get this Exception `Cannot find control with path: 'menu -> '`

Comment: @chris did you try `formControlName` the attribute not the property binding?

Comment: Yes but the Exception now is  `Cannot find control with path: 'menu -> i'`. If I write `[formControlName]="0"` it works but only with the first controller of the Array

Comment: did you specify the formArray before the [formControlName] ? Like formArrayName="menu"